# Maximise the difference of sum

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given are N books and a book stand.The book stand has only 2 empty shelves. Now we have two restrictions to keep the books on the shelves.

1. Only M (an integer) books can be placed on the top shelf and rest of the books are to be placed on the bottom shelf.
2. The difference between the sum of the weight of the books on the top shelf and the sum of weight of the books on the bottom shelf should be the most among all such arrangements possible.

Now, we will be given N and weights of all books and also M. we need to tell this maximum difference.

**Example :** Let N=5 and M=2 and books weights be [4,1,3,2,5] then here answer is 9.

How to approach this for given N weights and M.

**My Approach :** I first thought that it could be done with greedy approach by sorting the weights and then putting top M books in first shelf.I want to ask for the  correctness proof if this is correct ?
Else I want correct solution for this problem ?

**Constraints** : 1<=n<=10000 and we can assume 1<=m <= n / 2. Also 1<=p[i] <= 1000000

**Code :**

```
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    vector<long long int> a;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        long long int x;
        cin>>x;
        a.push_back(x);
    }
    sort(a.begin(),a.end());
    long long int upper=0,lower=0;
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        upper+=a[i];
    }
    for(int i=m;i<n;i++){
        lower+=a[i];
    }
    cout<<lower-upper<<"\n";
```

Comment: @almasshaikh I had mentioned about by thought.That i had implemented too.Should i post the code ?Because I just want to discuss about problem and not about the code

Comment: So paste your implementation's relevant part. Its not enough to just paste thought as this forum is to resolve issues with programming code and dont work on though process.

Comment: @almasshaikh I edited the post with code .Fine ?

Answer (score 0):

If the difference between the weight of the 2 shelves is to be **maximised** then I think that the greedy approach you outline will work. If the M heaviest books are on the top shelf then there is no book on the other shelf which will increase the difference if the two books are swapped.

If on the other hand you want to **minimize** the weight difference then the problem is NP-hard, see the entry [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).